# My Swift class appears in the auto-generated <target>-Swift.h file but not its function definitions

Tags: swift, ios8

Abstract:

The auto-generated -Swift.h file has my Swift class reference in it but none of its "func" definitions.  (note: i have other Swift classes with funcs that are listed in the auto-gen file and work just fine.)  Asking you to tell me why this other class/func is not being properly characterized in the Swift.h file

More detail:

Here is my auto-generated .swift.h file.  Notice that everything works fine with my first class called "Shape" and you can see that the function defs have been auto-generated for that class.  However, with my other swift class, "hiloBetFuncs", none of the function definitions (there is only one func) have been auto-generated.  So in my objective-C file, when I try and invoke the function on an instance of that class, the fun is not recognized as I type in Xcode.

Why has Swift generated the class ref in the -Swift.h but omitted the func definition.  I've included the fun below as well.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
@class nm_skin;
@class nm_theFeature;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9Golf_Whiz5Shape")
@interface Shape : NSObject
- (NSString *)testFunction;
- (void)skinDetails:(nm_skin *)skinny feature:(nm_theFeature *)feature;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9Golf_Whiz12hiloBetFuncs")
@interface hiloBetFuncs : NSObject
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Here is the hiloBetFuncs class (and function) itself.

```
import Foundation

class hiloBetFuncs : NSObject {


    func hilo_updateAllBetsforHole ( var hole : Int, result : Int, arrayOfBets : [nm_bet]) -> Int {

        var returnCodeValue : Int = 0
        let numberOfBetsInArray = arrayOfBets.count
        var previousHoleBetResult : Int
        var newHoleBetResult : Int

        // we are only dealing with 9-hole bets so if on the back nine, go ahead and drop the hole value
        // by 9 so that we can use the same holes 0-9 regardless.  (just makes things easier)
        if hole > 8
            {hole -= 9}

        for bet in arrayOfBets {

            if hole == 0 {

                // hole 0 is a bit of a special case, just cause you are not building off the bet
                // status from the previous hole.  This hole will be an autonomous 0, 1, or -1
                // just set it to the 'result' paramater that was sent in.

                bet.holeResults[hole] = result;
                println("after one hole, the primary bet has been updated with a status of \(result)");

            } else {

                //get pointer to the bet status as of the previous hole
                previousHoleBetResult = bet.holeResults[hole - 1] as Int

                //establish the bet status for the new hole, building from the previous hole's bet status
                newHoleBetResult = previousHoleBetResult + result

                // update the current hole's bet results with the newly calculated value
                bet.holeResults[hole] = newHoleBetResult;

            }

            // we want to return the bet status from the last active bet - if 2 or -2 then calling function will know to start a new bet.
            returnCodeValue = bet.holeResults[hole] as Int

        }

        println("ok, done the deed")

        // since the home team could be 2 down, the bet status could be a negative number 
        // convert to abs before returning.  Just checking for bet status, not care about who is leading.
        return abs(returnCodeValue)

    }

}
```

Comment: how is nm_bet defined?

Comment: nm_bet is an objc class that is defined as subclass of NSObject.  It is a very simple class with only a couple variables and no methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions with a `var` parameter are not exposed to Objective-C. As an example,
the Swift class

```
class SwiftClass : NSObject {
    func f1(x : Int) { }
    func f2(var x : Int) { }
}
```

appears in the bridging header `<module>-Swift.h` as

```
@interface SwiftClass : NSObject
- (void)f1:(NSInteger)x;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

If `f2` is explicitly marked for Objective-C export then the compilation fails:

```
@objc func f2(var x : Int) { }
// error: method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

As a workaround, you can declare the parameter as constant  (which is the default)
and make a variable copy:

```
func hilo_updateAllBetsforHole(theHole : Int, result : Int, arrayOfBets : [nm_bet]) -> Int {
    var hole = theHole
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to declare both of your class and methods definition as public.

```
public class MyClass {
    public func myMethod() -> Void {
        //your method implementation
    }
}
```

By default, Swift set access modifier to internal.
Hope this help.